# Does there exist an infinite geometric progression whose terms are all squares

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I am aware of the fact that the squares don't contain an infinite arithmetic subsequence, but I was wondering if the squares contain an infinite geometric sequence.

In other words, does there exist an infinite geometric sequence whose terms are all squares?

Comment: Does $1,1,1,1,\ldots$ count as geometric?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set $a=1$ and $r=4$, so the geometric progression becomes
$$1,4,16,64,256,\dots$$
which is equivalent to
$$1^2,2^2,4^2,8^2,16^2,\dots$$

Comment: Also, in general, if $r$ itself is a perfect square, then each term is also a perfect square.

Comment: If one were to generate a complete sequence of squares, would it follow this pattern? I.e starting with the basic integers - 0-9, select the perfect squares existing in the series, and then generate a GP sequence for each root of perfect square i.e (1,2(excluding two itself),3(excluding 3 itself), 5 (Excluding 5 itself), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_1 = m^2$ and $a_2 = n^2$ while $a_2 = r*a_1$ so $r = (\frac nm)^2$ a square of a rational.  If $r$ in lowest terms is $\frac jk$ then for $a_{n+1} = (\frac jk)^n*a_1$ to be an integer $k^n$ must divide $a_1$.  But that is true for all values of $n$ and the only way that is possible is if $k = 1$.

So if $a_1 = m^2$ and $r = j^2$ then... well that'll do it.  By induction if $a_n = l^2$ for some integer $l$ then $a_{n+1} = r*l^2 = j^2 *l^2 = (jl)^2$ is a prefect square.

Ex: $a_1 = 9=3^2$ and $r = 4$ then $a_{n+1} = 4^n*9= (2^n*3)^2$ for all $n \ge 1$.